# My google maps Polylines are all connected and I need each isoline to be separate - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I have spent ages creating for loops to iterate through all my coordinate arrays. 4 days later I have finally managed to get polylines to appear on my map. However, the start and end points for each line have all connected and now my map just looks like a mass of squiggles... any advice?

```
var path = [];

    var feat = lines['features'];

    var featlen = feat.length;
    console.log (featlen); //12

        for (var i = 0; i < featlen; i ++){
        var coord = feat[i]['geometry']['coordinates'];
        var coordlen = coord.length;

            for (var n = 0; n < coordlen; n++){
            var coordinates = coord[n];
            var coordinateslen = coordinates.length;
                for (k=0; k < coordinateslen; k++){
                var network = coordinates[k];

                path.push({lat: parseFloat(network['1']), lng: parseFloat (network['0'])});
                console.log(path);
                }
            }
        }

newIsolines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        map: map,
        clickable: false,
        strokeColor: lineColour,
        strokeOpacity: opacity,
        strokeWeight: 1
    }));

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `path` and `Polyline` for each feature:

```
  var path = [];

  var feat = lines['features'];

  var featlen = feat.length;
  console.log(featlen); //12

  for (var i = 0; i < featlen; i++) {
    var coord = feat[i]['geometry']['coordinates'];
    var coordlen = coord.length;

    for (var n = 0; n < coordlen; n++) {
      var coordinates = coord[n];
      var coordinateslen = coordinates.length;
      for (k = 0; k < coordinateslen; k++) {
        var network = coordinates[k];

        path.push({
          lat: parseFloat(network['1']),
          lng: parseFloat(network['0'])
        });
        console.log(path);
      }
    }
    newIsolines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: path,
      map: map,
      clickable: false,
      strokeColor: lineColour,
      strokeOpacity: opacity,
      strokeWeight: 1
    }));
    path = [];
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j3Lgrafo/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var newIsolines = [];
  var lineColour = 'blue';
  var opacity = 1.0;
  var lines = {
    features: [{
      geometry: {
        coordinates: [
          [
            [-122.1410751, 37.4688273],
            [-122.1419, 37.4419]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }, {
      geometry: {
        coordinates: [
          [
            [-122.1817252, 37.4529598],
            [-122.20302091, 37.4335499]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }]
  };
  var path = [];

  var feat = lines['features'];

  var featlen = feat.length;
  console.log(featlen); //12

  for (var i = 0; i < featlen; i++) {
    var coord = feat[i]['geometry']['coordinates'];
    var coordlen = coord.length;

    for (var n = 0; n < coordlen; n++) {
      var coordinates = coord[n];
      var coordinateslen = coordinates.length;
      for (k = 0; k < coordinateslen; k++) {
        var network = coordinates[k];

        path.push({
          lat: parseFloat(network['1']),
          lng: parseFloat(network['0'])
        });
        console.log(path);
      }
    }
    newIsolines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: path,
      map: map,
      clickable: false,
      strokeColor: lineColour,
      strokeOpacity: opacity,
      strokeWeight: 2
    }));
    path = [];
  }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful and has worked for some of the Polylines, but some of them are still connected. Is this because the loop is maybe stopping at some point? Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: That is a different question.  Please provide a [mcve] with a sample of the problematic input data.